# Free space regex option (Pattern.COMMENTS) not working as expected

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to detect profanity using regex. But I want to detect the word even if they've spaced out the word like "Profa nity". However when using the "(?x)" option it still doesn't want to detect.

I currently got:

```
(?ix).*Bad Word.*
```

I've tried using http://www.rubular.com to debug the expression with not luck.

If it helps in any way it's for at Teamspeak Bot where I want to kick the user for having banned words in their name. In the config it refers to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html where I can't find anything relating to the (?) options.

The bot itself can be found here: https://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/51286-JTS3ServerMod-Multifunction-TS3-Server-Bot-(Idle-Record-Away-Mute-Welcome-)

Comment: I can forsee problems here.  How do we know that "fi**sh** **it**erator" is not really legitimate text?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen In the config there are specified multiple regex filters. The bot run through them all, and will kick the user if there is a match. Here is the config: https://hastebin.com/natewiwiku.shell The reason I want to detect no matter the whitespace is because people keeps using the banned words by splitting them into pieces.

Comment: the x modifier does not what you think, x stands for extended and changes the way the pattern is interpreted: Spaces and text after a # in the pattern are ignored.

Comment: How about this: https://regex101.com/r/er84V1/1

Comment: X stands for expanded mode. It ignores all whitespace in the regex. The regex can be made into a [readable regex](http://www.regexformat.com). In your case `(?ix).*Bad Word.*` is actually interpreted as `(?i).*BadWord.*` So, you'd have to either escape the space `(?ix).*Bad \ Word.*` or put it into a class `(?ix).*Bad [ ] Word.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when using the "(?x)" option it still doesn't want to detect

The `(?x)` is an embedded flag option (also known as an inline modifier/option) enables the `Pattern.COMMENTS` option, also known as free-spacing mode that enables comments inside regular expressions and makes the regex engine ignore all regular whitespace inside the pattern. As per [Free-Spacing in Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html):

> In free-spacing mode, whitespace between regular expression tokens is ignored. Whitespace includes spaces, tabs, and line breaks. Note that only whitespace between tokens is ignored. `a b c` is the same as `abc` in free-spacing mode. But `\ d` and `\d` are not the same. The former matches  `d`, while the latter matches a digit. `\d` is a single regex token composed of a backslash and a `"d"`. Breaking up the token with a space gives you an escaped space (which matches a space), and a literal "d".
>
> Likewise, grouping modifiers cannot be broken up. `(?>atomic)` is the same as `(?> ato mic )` and as `( ?>ato mic)`. They all match the same [atomic group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). They're not the same as `(? >atomic)`. The latter is a syntax error. The `?>` grouping modifier is a single element in the regex syntax, and must stay together. This is true for all such constructs, including [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), [named groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), etc.

So,  to match a single space in a pattern with the `(?x)` modifier, you need to escape it:

```
String reg = "(?ix).*Bad\\ Word.*";   // Escaped space matches a space in free spacing mode
String reg = "(?ix).* Bad\\ Word .*"; // More formatting spaces, same pattern
```

**NOTE** that you *CAN'T* put the space into a character class to make it meaningful in a Java regex. See below:

> Java, however, does not treat a character class as a single token in free-spacing mode. Java does ignore spaces, line breaks, and comments inside character classes. So in Java's free-spacing mode, `[abc]` is identical to `[ a b c ]`.

Besides, I think you actually wanted to make sure your pattern can match full strings that may contain line breaks. That means, you need `(?s)`, `Pattern.DOTALL`, modifier:

```
String reg = "(?is).*Bad Word.*";
```

Also, to match any whitespace, you may rely on `\s`:

```
String reg = "(?ix).*Bad\\sWord.*"; // To only match 1 whitespace
String reg = "(?ix).*Bad\\s+Word.*"; // To account for 1 or more whitespaces
```

Comment: Are you quoting this guy again. This: `Likewise, grouping modifiers cannot be broken up. (?>atomic) is the same as (?> ato mic ) and as ( ?>ato mic). They all match the same atomic group` He should be saying _`all grouping construct syntax cannot be broken up in expanded mode`_ and be done with it. Therefore, in expanded mode  `( ?>ato mic)` is an _error_ as is `(? >ato mic)` and  `( ? > ato mic)` and `(  ?:ato ster)` and `( ?(1) ato nial)`. Maybe you should leave out that misinformation so as not to confuse others who don't know this.

Comment: @sln Your comment is not relevant for Java. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/X33GAY) where `"( ?>\\d+ \\p{L}+)(?!-)"` matches `123aa` in `123aa567bb-`, and thus **in Java**, *`(?>atomic)` is the same as `(?> ato mic )` and as `( ?>ato mic)`*. As for most other regex flavors, and maybe even all of them (I have not tested), what you say is correct (see [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/cZ33rQ) where `( ?>\d+ \p{L}+)` is no longer an atomic group in free-spacing mode).